# rviz - only base_link works

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone! At first, sorry for my English :( I`ve got a problem. I'm beginner at ROS (melody, ubuntu 18.04). I learing how to do a URDF file, i'm using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ale55LcdZeE&list=PLK0b4e05LnzaY2QxaTHkvLJPNVNx-ssDW&index=24 .

When i start rviz a only see a `base_link` (without `link_01`), I try to change  URDF file but it doesn`t helped.
this is my xacro file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<robot name="mrm" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1 1" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    </link>

      <joint name="base_link__link_01" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.5"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_01"/>
      </joint>

    <link name="link_01">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.35" length="0.4" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    </link>
</robot>
```

and launch file:

```
<launch>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find mrm_description)/urdf/mrm.xacro'"/>
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
    
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
        <param name="use_gui" value="True"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

i would be very grateful for Your help!
Pawel :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317465/rviz----only-base_link-works/) by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SleepyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39792/sleepyturtle/) on 2019-03-05**:
I've copied your setup and it works fine for me. Maybe you're not setting up rviz correctly? What do you mean by "only see a base_link (without link_01)"?

**Comment by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on 2019-03-05**:
Hey! Thank You for Your answer! i change the value of radius(more than one), and value of length(also more than one) and it`s works(i see base_link and link_01)! but when i change this value (radius and length<1), the cylinder(link_01) disappears :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a locale problem. If you've not configured your machine to use `en_US.UTF-8`, the urdf parser will try to use commas (`,`) for floating point nrs, and you're using dots (`.`).

See #q272692 for an older duplicate.

Note: just to clarify: this is an issue with `urdfdom`. The solution is not to override locale everywhere, that would be just a work-around.

See the linked duplicate for more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on 2019-03-06**:
Thank You a lot!